# Can't locate URI/Escape.pm in @INC on AWS lambda

Tags: perl, aws-lambda, sh

I have an AWS Lamba function in python that generates a url using a shell script.
The input parameters to the shell script is provided by the python code.
The shell script uses perl to URL encode the required URL.
This script runs fine when I run in locally;however on AWS lamba looks like the perl `MURI` is not installed. Would appreciate if there is alternative way to do this or any other suggestions to go about it.I am doing URL encode by the following commands. The error I see in lambda logs is:

```
Can't locate URI/Escape.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Code in the script is

```sh
cred=$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape($ARGV[0]);' "$PARM1/$DATE/$PUBLIC_REGION/$SERVICE_NAME/request")
FULLDT=$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape($ARGV[0]);' "$FULLDT")
SESSION_TOKEN=$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape($ARGV[0]);' "$SESSION_TOKEN")
```

Comment: `cpan URI::Escape` to install

Comment: Python script calling Perl to parse URL? This sounds completely wrong. Python is perfectly capable of parsing URLs using native python libraries. Don't get me wrong; I love Perl too.

Answer (score 6):

> however on AWS lamba looks like the perl MURI is not installed

You're almost right. the `-M` is a command-line option telling Perl to load a module. The complete module name is "URI::Escape".

And, yes, that module isn't part of a standard Perl installation, so you'll need to install it separately as part of whatever process you use to set up the environment that your lambda runs in. The simplest approach is probably to run:

```
cpan URI::Escape
```

But I'm not sure how that would translate to the lambda environment.

Comment: In Lambda, the root of the deployment package zip file becomes `/var/task`, so copying the module into the zip (i.e. `Escape.pm` in a directory called `URI` in the root of the zip) would allow you to use `perl -I/var/task -MURI::Escape ...` which would be *the start* of what's needed (next: dependencies...).  I used this stragegy with solid success when I wanted the ability to call `Storable::thaw()` from Node.js in Lambda (`Storable` was already there, of course, but other things I needed for usable thawing, like `DateTime`, were not).  In this case, though... the effort seems unjustifiable.

Comment: Also note that modules generally can't just be copied around, they need to be installed as well as their dependencies, and only pureperl modules (which URI::Escape is) can be used in a different Perl from the one that installed it generally.